# How to compute percent of variance explained in X and Y for each component of a PLSR?

Tags: regression, matlab, partial-least-squares

I am not a mathematician and my question is probably trivial but I did not manage to find an answer on the web.

I need to compute the percent of variance explained (eigenvalues?) in X and Y for each component of a PLS regression from loadings and scores produced by a PLSR function.

I am using Matlab.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to CV and +1. Can you refer to the specific function you are using? Also, how many variables do you have in Y, is it only one or many?

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I thought I have begun my question with hello and terminated it with thank you but this has disappeared. I am using the IToolbox functions (http://www.models.life.ku.dk/itoolbox).
I can have one or many variables in Y, it will depend on the purpose:
One variable in Y: exploratory investigation of the relationship between the wavelength and a measured parameter
Many variables in Y: prediction routine
Thank you